# Can we authenticate with Salesforce via Basic Authentication?

Tags: api, authentication

Can Basic Authentication be used to execute Salesforce REST calls?

For eg: `/services/data/vXX.0/sobjects/Contact/`

Added Request Header as

`Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

Tried both of following combinations, but no success.

`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Base64 encoding of username:password`

`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Base64 encoding of username:password+securitytoken`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Salesforce currently uses OAuth 2.0 for authentication. The only other option is to obtain and submit a user's session Id with each request.

Both methods are detailed in [Step Two: Set Up Authorization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm) in the REST API documentation.

There is also [Digging Deeper into OAuth 2.0 on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com), which you may find helpful.